# Simple way to disable DHCP for specific WiFi network(s)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I would like my laptop to disable DHCP for only one WiFi network. I often hibernate the laptop, change locations, and wake it up.

One posting abuot settings that are specific to a WiFi network is at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1123456/specific-dns-setting-for-one-wifi-connection), assuming that an "adapter" is the same as a WiFi network.  But I don't want to delve into PowerShell and event driven commands.  It would be easier to manually ensure that DHCP is disabled on a specific network.

Another post [here](http://superuser.com/questions/851589/specific-ip-settings-for-different-wifi-access-points) requires DHCP to fail (which it won't).

The above post also refers to [a blog](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-windows-script-change-network-settings-fly) about writing VB script, but again, I'm wondering if a simpler way has arisen in the last 7 years?

Comment: I would suggest the answer lies not in your device, but in the network. If a situation is needed where your device should have the same IP address all the time then a static DHCP reservation should be made in the network so your device always is offered the same IP address from the DHCP server. This is usually available in even the simplest of routers to the most high end equipment or dedicated DHCP server.

Comment: OK, that's going to take some web searching on my part.  Thanks for pointing out that this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it simple because Windows has IP configuration for adapter (network card, interface), not for network. So you have to change the IP settings somehow.

If you have some coding experience you can easy handle the moment when a WiFi Network connection state changed (disconnected, connected, re-connected) and change the IP configuration dinamically. Its hard to code IP changing using Win32 API but you can easy call PowerShell script from your monitoring application (which is described in one of the answer you reffered to).